# Do Apple "Provisioning Profiles" need to be regenerated when the "App Identifier" has its APNS certificate updated?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

I am trying to understand the relationship between App Identifiers and Provisioning Profiles.

I have a Provisioning Profile that has "Push" enabled, but the App Identifier did not have any push certificate added. If I then edit the App Identifier to include the certificate(s), does a new Provisioning Profile need to be created to reflect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the apple push notification service certificate has no effect on the provisional profile , (Unless you enabled push notifications in the app bundle id now) . You will only have to update the provisional profiles if you either updated your app bundle id with any new capabilities or if you updated your developer certificates / distribution certificates